# controlling pgfplots axis labels

Tags: pgfplots

I prepare Multiple Y-axis plot -4 Ys YY-YY 
But I have only one problem, I want my x number only show 0,4,8,12,20 time 
But when I write commander show me all from 0 to 20 
How I will do this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{document} 
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1} 
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
% f1 
\begin{axis}[ 
color=black, 
scale only axis, 
xmin=0.5, 
xmax=20.5, 
xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}, 
xlabel={$y$}, 
ymin=1, 
ymax=2, 
ytick={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0}, 
yticklabels={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0}, 
y axis line style={blue}, 
ytick style={blue}, 
yticklabel style={blue}, 
axis x line*=bottom, 
axis y line*=left, 
tick align = outside,] 
\addplot [ 
color=blue, 
solid, 
line width=1.5pt, 
mark size=2.7pt, 
mark size=2.7pt, 
mark=square*, 
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=blue}] 
table[row sep=crcr]{ 
1 1.09754040499941\\ 
2 1.12698681629351\\ 
3 1.14188633862722\\ 
4 1.15761308167755\\ 
5 1.27849821886705\\ 
6 1.42176128262627\\ 
7 1.48537564872284\\ 
8 1.54688151920498\\ 
9 1.63235924622541\\ 
10 1.79220732955955\\ 
11 1.8002804688888\\ 
12 1.81472368639318\\ 
13 1.90579193707562\\ 
14 1.91337585613902\\ 
15 1.91573552518907\\ 
16 1.95716694824295\\ 
17 1.9575068354343\\ 
18 1.9594924263929\\ 
19 1.96488853519928\\ 
20 1.97059278176062\\}; 
\end{axis} 
% f2 
\begin{axis}[ 
color=mycolor2, 
scale only axis, 
xmin=0.5, 
xmax=20.5, 
ymin=2, 
ymax=3, 
ytick={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0}, 
yticklabels={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0}, 
axis x line*=none, 
axis y line*=left, 
ylabel={$x$}, 
ylabel style=black, 
hide x axis, 
tick align =outside,] 
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=-1.5cm} } 
\addplot [ 
color=mycolor2, 
solid, 
line width=1.5pt, 
mark size=2.7pt, 
mark=*, 
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2}] 
table[row sep=crcr]{ 
1 2.03183284637742\\ 
2 2.03444608050291\\ 
3 2.03571167857419\\ 
4 2.04617139063115\\ 
5 2.09713178123585\\ 
6 2.17118668781156\\ 
7 2.27692298496089\\ 
8 2.31709948006086\\ 
9 2.39222701953417\\ 
10 2.65547789017756\\ 
11 2.65574069915659\\ 
12 2.67873515485777\\ 
13 2.69482862297582\\ 
14 2.70604608801961\\ 
15 2.74313246812492\\ 
16 2.75774013057833\\ 
17 2.82345782832729\\ 
18 2.84912930586878\\ 
19 2.93399324775755\\ 
20 2.95022204883836\\}; 
\end{axis} 
% f3 
\begin{axis}[ 
color=mycolor1, 
scale only axis, 
xmin=0.5, 
xmax=20.5, 
ymin=3, 
ymax=4, 
ytick={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0}, 
yticklabels={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0}, 
ytick style={mycolor1}, 
axis x line*=none, 
axis y line*=right, 
hide x axis, 
tick align = outside,] 
\addplot [ 
color=mycolor1, 
solid, 
line width=1.5pt, 
mark size=2.7pt, 
mark=triangle*, 
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1}] 
table[row sep=crcr]{ 
1 3.11899768155838\\ 
2 3.16261173519463\\ 
3 3.18687260455438\\ 
4 3.22381193949114\\ 
5 3.27602507699858\\ 
6 3.34038572666613\\ 
7 3.38155845709301\\ 
8 3.4387443596564\\ 
9 3.4455862007109\\ 
10 3.48976439578823\\ 
11 3.49836405198214\\ 
12 3.58526775097978\\ 
13 3.64631301011127\\ 
14 3.65509800397384\\ 
15 3.67970267685367\\ 
16 3.70936483085807\\ 
17 3.75468668198236\\ 
18 3.765516788149\\ 
19 3.79519990113706\\ 
20 3.95974395851608\\}; 
\end{axis} 
% f4 
\begin{axis}[ 
color=red, 
scale only axis, 
xmin=0.5, 
xmax=20.5, 
ymin=4, 
ymax=5, 
ytick={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0}, 
yticklabels={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0}, 
axis x line*=none, 
axis y line*=right, 
hide x axis, 
tick align = outside,] 
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=1.5cm}} 
\addplot [ 
color=red, 
solid, 
line width=1.5pt, 
mark size=2.7pt, 
mark=triangle*, 
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=red}] 
table[row sep=crcr]{ 
1 4.13862444282868\\ 
2 4.14929400555906\\ 
3 4.19659525043121\\ 
4 4.24352496872499\\ 
5 4.25108385797603\\ 
6 4.25428217897153\\ 
7 4.25509511545927\\ 
8 4.25750825412374\\ 
9 4.34998376598481\\ 
10 4.47328884890273\\ 
11 4.50595705166514\\ 
12 4.5472155299638\\ 
13 4.61604467614664\\ 
14 4.69907672265669\\ 
15 4.75126705930565\\ 
16 4.81428482606882\\ 
17 4.84071725598366\\ 
18 4.8909032525358\\ 
19 4.92926362318723\\ 
20 4.95929142520544\\}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}% 
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, you can mark code sections using the `{}`button in the editor. Also please try to give descriptive titles and tags to your question "problem in latex" could apply to almost every question here. See my edit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you want to see... does changing the line `xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}, ` to `xtick={0,4,...,20},` get you what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Put `xtick={0,4,8,12,20},` in the first one.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{1,0,1}
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0,0.498039215803146,0}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% f1
\begin{axis}[
color=black,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
%xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
xtick={0,4,8,12,20},   %%%<------------- here
xlabel={$y$},
ymin=1,
ymax=2,
ytick={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0},
yticklabels={1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0},
y axis line style={blue},
ytick style={blue},
yticklabel style={blue},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,    
tick align = outside,]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=square*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=180,fill=blue}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1.09754040499941\\
2 1.12698681629351\\
3 1.14188633862722\\
4 1.15761308167755\\
5 1.27849821886705\\
6 1.42176128262627\\
7 1.48537564872284\\
8 1.54688151920498\\
9 1.63235924622541\\
10 1.79220732955955\\
11 1.8002804688888\\
12 1.81472368639318\\
13 1.90579193707562\\
14 1.91337585613902\\
15 1.91573552518907\\
16 1.95716694824295\\
17 1.9575068354343\\
18 1.9594924263929\\
19 1.96488853519928\\
20 1.97059278176062\\};
\end{axis}
% f2
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor2,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=2,
ymax=3,
ytick={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0},
yticklabels={2.0,2.2,2.4,2.6,2.8,3.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=left,
ylabel={$x$},
ylabel style=black,
hide x axis,
tick align =outside,]
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=-1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=-1.5cm} }
\addplot [
color=mycolor2,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor2}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 2.03183284637742\\
2 2.03444608050291\\
3 2.03571167857419\\
4 2.04617139063115\\
5 2.09713178123585\\
6 2.17118668781156\\
7 2.27692298496089\\
8 2.31709948006086\\
9 2.39222701953417\\
10 2.65547789017756\\
11 2.65574069915659\\
12 2.67873515485777\\
13 2.69482862297582\\
14 2.70604608801961\\
15 2.74313246812492\\
16 2.75774013057833\\
17 2.82345782832729\\
18 2.84912930586878\\
19 2.93399324775755\\
20 2.95022204883836\\};
\end{axis}
% f3
\begin{axis}[
color=mycolor1,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=3,
ymax=4,
ytick={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0},
yticklabels={3.0,3.2,3.4,3.6,3.8,4.0},
ytick style={mycolor1},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis,
tick align = outside,]
\addplot [
color=mycolor1,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,fill=mycolor1}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 3.11899768155838\\
2 3.16261173519463\\
3 3.18687260455438\\
4 3.22381193949114\\
5 3.27602507699858\\
6 3.34038572666613\\
7 3.38155845709301\\
8 3.4387443596564\\
9 3.4455862007109\\
10 3.48976439578823\\
11 3.49836405198214\\
12 3.58526775097978\\
13 3.64631301011127\\
14 3.65509800397384\\
15 3.67970267685367\\
16 3.70936483085807\\
17 3.75468668198236\\
18 3.765516788149\\
19 3.79519990113706\\
20 3.95974395851608\\};
\end{axis}
% f4
\begin{axis}[
color=red,
scale only axis,
xmin=0.5,
xmax=20.5,
ymin=4,
ymax=5,
ytick={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0},
yticklabels={4.0,4.2,4.4,4.6,4.8,5.0},
axis x line*=none,
axis y line*=right,
hide x axis,
tick align = outside,]
\pgfplotsset{every outer y axis line/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every tick/.style={xshift=1.5cm}, every y tick label/.style={xshift=1.5cm}}
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
line width=1.5pt,
mark size=2.7pt,
mark=triangle*,
mark options={solid,,rotate=270,fill=red}]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 4.13862444282868\\
2 4.14929400555906\\
3 4.19659525043121\\
4 4.24352496872499\\
5 4.25108385797603\\
6 4.25428217897153\\
7 4.25509511545927\\
8 4.25750825412374\\
9 4.34998376598481\\
10 4.47328884890273\\
11 4.50595705166514\\
12 4.5472155299638\\
13 4.61604467614664\\
14 4.69907672265669\\
15 4.75126705930565\\
16 4.81428482606882\\
17 4.84071725598366\\
18 4.8909032525358\\
19 4.92926362318723\\
20 4.95929142520544\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have some problems